# how to give an changable path to an excel constructor in c#?

Tags: c#

I am working with excel files (create, open, write and save). I want to be able to change the path. so probably I should work with string variables.

```
 Excel ex2 = new Excel(@"myexcel.xlsx");
```

How can I replace a variable with the path: `@"myexcel.xlsx"`? If I define a `string` variable, what would be its *value*?

Comment: the complete path to the excel file - C:\Users\....\Folder\test.xlsx

Comment: Are you asking a question you already answered by yourself..?

Comment: but it doesn't work in this way

Comment: Please tell us what is that you are trying to acheive, are you **opening excel / Creating sheet / Saving etc** ??

Answer (score 0):

do you mean

```cs
string filePath = @"myexcel.xslx"; /// you can remove the '@' here as the string doesn't contain any backlashes
Excel ex2 = new Excel(filePath);
```

See [String Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8)

—UPDATE—

Go to file explorer, shift+ right click the excel file, *copy path*, paste the copied path in your code as the path to file (with @)

Comment: using primitive aliases is better than the framework classes

Comment: but it causes to An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Comment: the program seems to not assume the filePath as a rigth pass.

Comment: If your code works, this will, if not (you didn’t mention that), then you probably aren’t getting the full path to the file, check the updated answer @N pnj

Comment: I tried  Excel ex2 = new Excel(@"myexcel.xlsx"); and it works. when I use string just like you recommend first, it doesn't work and causes that error

Comment: that's improbable it works hardcoded and not via variables, can you show us a screen shot